# Can I set a different Reply-To address from the From address for a Mailchimp campaign?

Tags: mailchimp

As the title indicates, I'd like replies to my Mailchimp campaign to go to a different email address from the From address appearing as the sender. Is this possible?

I couldn't see an obvious way to do it when I created a test campaign, but I thought it might be worth asking anyway.

Comment: As I recall from my notes back in 2015, there had been a time when one can send from one address and funnel all replies through a different "Reply-To" field. I bet MailChimp should have taken this feature away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also wanting to have a different "reply to" and "sender" email for Mailchimp.

I keep searching for the answer to this but, I cannot find anything.

I don't think this is a current option for a Mailchimp campaign.

Comment: I agree; there doesn't appear to be a way... thanks for your answer! You might like to upvote the question if you think it would be of interest to others.

Answer (score 3):

The issue only happens when you use the "Send a Test E-mail". If the e-mail is triggered normally (like when someone subscribes), the e-mail will have the correct address.

https://www.indiehackers.com/forum/help-mailchimp-reply-email-is-weird-ca2111aaff

Comment: THIS answered the question for me (whew thank you)

Answer (score 1):

While not 100% exactly what the OP asked for, I was after a way to have replies to our marketing emails go to our customer service staff rather than the mailer email address, and it appears Mailchimp now offer this as a feature in 'Conversations'. Looks like it has to be set up on a per-campaign basis, but may be helpful nonetheless. Only requires that the email you want replies copied to has an account set up in Mailchimp: https://mailchimp.com/help/set-up-and-use-conversations/